# Creating a relationship when filling in a Profile (Revisited)

Tags: contacts, profile, relationships, forms

I am reposting this ticket from 5 years ago because I really need to be able to do the same thing using CiviCRM 5.39 and Wordpress 5.8. Does anyone know if this is possible now, perhaps using an extension, or if there's another workaround?

> I love the way the "Employee of" relationship can be created simply by
> adding the "Current Employer" field to a profile. Is there a corollary
> for other relationships? I need to be able to track if an event
> registrant is connected to another external partnering organization.
> However, I don't retain the membership information for the partnering
> organizations.
>
> Quick example: Create a "Church Member of" relationship to an
> Organization/Church while signing up for a training.
>
> (If I missed this in the docs, oops!, please forgive me.) It seems
> that most are using Drupal WebForms, which is, um, difficult? on
> WordPress.

Comment: This can be done via Caldera Forms integration now i believe

Answer (score 0):

Long ago I did this for a local political group. If I recall correctly I setup a custom field in the contact with the label "is member of" and a boolean.

I then had to create a smart group with all members that had "yes" in that field and I would apply that relationship to all members of the smartgroup with a recurring task.

Karl